# How to use Laravel Echo in SvelteKit (SSR)?

Tags: laravel, websocket, svelte, laravel-echo

How do you set-up Laravel Echo in Svelte (SSR)?

I tried the following code from the documentation but it doesn't seem to work.

```js
import Echo from "laravel-echo"

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'your-pusher-key',
    wsHost: window.location.hostname,
    wsPort: 6001,
    forceTLS: false,
    disableStats: true,
});
```

The code shows an error that `window` is undefined.

I also tried searching for instructions or references online but can't seem to find one for setting up Laravel Echo.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You've got to wait for window context.
If you're using sveltekit:

```js
import { browser } from '$app/environment';
if (browser) {
   //your window.Pusher code
}
```

Else if you're using vanilla svelte

```
   import { onMount } from 'svelte'
   onMount(async()=>{ 
        //Your window.pusher code
   })
```